# Backbone include in the head?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure out why my backbone code wasn't working. I finally made it work by switching:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically moving the script includes from the `head` to the `body`. Can someone explain to me why this would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `application.js` module deals with the elements of the page then it's expected behavior since when your script is at the end of `body` tag the page is already rendered and you can work with its elements.
And when your script is included in the `head` element, the page is still not rendered but the script is going to execute and try to deal with the elements which are still absent.
Therefore you have to include your script at the end of the `body` tag or start its execution in `window.onload` or `$(document).ready` event handler.

Comment: Interesting. I suspected it might be that. But I usually use `$(function() { //Code Here }); ` which I was told is the same as document.ready

Comment: Just noticed the jQuery version is quite old. After updating it, it seems to work. Cheers!

Comment: @andy your versions of backbone and underscore are pretty old as well, might want to replace those with current versions too.

Comment: @steveax I did thanks! :) It turns out the tutorial I was using was pretty old